# Angular : how to stop browser refresh without using confirmation or alert to show custom modal say unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, angular-ui-router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rb9i.jpg)I need to show modal[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmCeB.jpg) based on unsaved form Changes it's working as expected for angular route

Issue : popup does not work while browser refresh/ back button/ url change manually

Resolution for :
How to stop browser reference without using confirmation box or alert,
How can we show bootstrap modal while page refresh manually on page unload

I am expecting page not to be refresh upon changing url manually and should show custom component modal

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Here's](https://angularlovefest.com/index.php/2022/08/04/prevent-navigation-from-forms-with-changed-data/) a good blog post. You can ONLY use a route-guard + `window:beforeunload` to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this reload, you can use Angular's `CanDeactivate` route guard along with a modal dialog. Here's how you can achieve this:

1- First, create a custom component for your modal dialog. This will serve as the confirmation dialog when there are unsaved changes. For example, you can create a component called `UnsavedChangesDialogComponent`.

2- Next, create Routeguard to check for unsaved changes. You can use the `CanDeactivate` route guard to achieve this.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
  canDeactivate: () => boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class UnsavedChangesGuard
  implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate>
{
  canDeactivate(
    component: CanComponentDeactivate
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

3- Implement the `canDeactivate` method in the form where you have unsaved changes. This method accepts true or false. Return true or false based on whether there are changes or not.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-component',
  templateUrl: 'form-component.html',
})
export class YourFormComponent {
  // ...

  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    if (this.formChanged) {
      // Display the modal dialog
      // Return false to prevent navigation
      this.showUnsavedChangesModal();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private showUnsavedChangesModal() {
    // Use a service to open your custom modal component
    // ...
  }
}
```

4- Finally, apply the UnsavedChangesGuard to the routes where you want to prevent navigation with unsaved changes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'your-form',
    component: YourFormComponent,
    canDeactivate: [UnsavedChangesGuard], // This is the code that checks
  },
  // ...other routes
];
```